# Piano length of Beep in C Language

Tags: c, beep, piano

I'm trying to develop a simple piano in C with Beep function like "Beep(261,100);" but I don't know how to make the program recognize for how long the person is holding a key, so it would beep without stop.
I have seen this on another forum but I don't know how to use it:

```
if (note == 'a'){Beep(261, length);}
```

and at the end of the program:

```
char notes[5] = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"};

int frequencies[5] = {261,130,75,32,16}; //these aren't accurate numbers but whatever

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){

    if (note == notes[i]){Beep(frequencies[i], length)}

}
```

a map would be better but I don't feel like implementing it. The concept is the same.

Comment: It won't work. C recognizes one step at once. The user touch is a step. So you can't beep while the key is being pressed.

Comment: I have tried doing the same thing a while ago. Unfortunately it won't work the way you wanted :/

Comment: A key-press can be broken down into two discrete events. You need to listen for the key-down and key-up events, which are going to be specific to the framework you are using.

Comment: Even if you do implement system-specific functions to determine if a key is pressed, or to give key events, you still can't call `Beep` in real time, because you don't know what interval to give. Note the [MS man page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms679277%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says *... does not return control to its caller until the sound finishes*. You can only realistically use `Beep` for playback, or for short fixed length tones.

Comment: So is there a way to do this, including using a special framework ?
You messages discourage me... And I need to make a GUI, is there anyone OK to helping me ? Do you know a WYSIWYG solution  ? (I'm nerd un programmation but I want to learn C language so if someone is motivated to let me learn it...)